# Argument must be in bytes or unicode, got list

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm coding a Scrapy project. I've tested everything, but when I parse a page it returns `TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'list'` I've tested everything in the shell using [this link.](http://www.grailed.com/listings/105) And I can't seem to find where it's having a problem. All of my shell commands returned only one item (i.e. there was no comma.)

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose
from scraper_app.items import Grailed

class GrailedSpider(Spider):
    name = "grailed"
    allowed_domains = ["grailed.com"]
    base_url = "https://www.grailed.com/listings/"
    start_urls = ["https://www.grailed.com/listings/100"]

    for i in range(100, 150):
        start_urls.append(base_url + str(i))

    item_fields = {
        'created': '//ul[@class = "horizontal-list listing-metadata-list clearfix"]/li[@class="horizontal-list-item listing-metadata-item"][1]/span[2]/text()',
        'title_size': '//h1[@class = "designer"]/div/text()',
        'original_price': '//ul[@class = "horizontal-list price-drops clearfix"]/li/text()',
        'followers': '//div[@class = "listing-followers"]/p/text()',
        'shipping_price': '//div[@class = "listing-shipping"]/p/text()',
        'sellers_wardrobe': '//div[@class = "user-widget medium"]/a/text()',
        'bought_and_sold': '//div[@class = "user-widget-bottom"]/p[@class= "bought-and-sold"]/text()[1]',
        'feedback_score': '//div[@class = "green seller-score-top"]/text()[2]'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # iterate over urls
        for url in selector.xpath(self.start_urls):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(Grailed(), selector=url)

            # define processors
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()

            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
                loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
            yield loader.load_item()
```

The traceback shows

```
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.grailed.com/listings/144> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/phillipblack/Projects/scrape_workspace/grailed/scraper_app/spiders/grailed_spider.py", line 55, in parse
    for url in selector.xpath(self.start_urls):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 97, in xpath
    smart_strings=self._lxml_smart_strings)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1507, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:52198)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 295, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:151999)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1391, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:27100)
TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'list'
```

Comment: Show the whole traceback.

Comment: Your error is your for loop `for url in selector.xpath(self.start_urls)`. Add a for loop before this one i recommend so that you send just an item from the list to selector.xpath like it is expecting.

Comment: @Maikflow Sorry, this my first project. How would this work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
for url in selector.xpath(self.start_urls):
```

`selector.xpath` should receive an string, with an xpath command. I see that you want to get urls, so maybe something like `//a/@href`:

```
selector.xpath('//a/@href')
```

Comment: I'm trying to have it parse all of the urls that were defined in the previous for loop.